# How to set mfrow/mfcol in python

Tags: python, r, jupyter, rpy2

Through `rpy2` in jupyter, you may plot your data directly from python using `R` objects. How can you set `par(mfrow=c(1,2)` in python?

For instance, I want to automatically feed a matrix with variable size from python and plot it (among other statistical analyses) using `rpy2`. But instead of plotting a single boxplot, I want all of them to be output.

Here's some sample code

```
import rpy2.ipython
import rpy2.robjects as ro
import scipy as sp
import re #python for regex
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
rpy2.robjects.numpy2ri.activate()
%load_ext rpy2.ipython
%R

test=[[1,3,2],[6,5,7,8,9]]

def funtoanalyze(grouparray):
    a={}
    data=numpy.array(test)
    for ig in range(len(grouparray)):
        key=grouparray[ig]
        value=data[ig]
        a[key]=value
        next
    rbox=ro.r('boxplot')
    for gro in a:    
        datar=a[gro]
        ro.r('dev.new()')
        rbox(ro.FloatVector(datar[:]),xlab="",main=gro)
    return

funtoanalyze(["group33","group2"]) #only plots last group
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your use of `%load_ext rpy2.ipython` suggests that you want to have your figure in the jupyter notebook.

R is using "graphical devices" to output figures, and calling `par(mfrow=c(...))` will either put the setting in an open graphical device or open a new default device and set the parameter.

The "magic" `%%R` is scanning if figures were generated on default devices and display them in the notebook. The following should work:

```
%%R

par(mfrow=c(1,2))
plot(0, 0)
plot(0, 0)
```

If you do not want to use the R magic, there are other utilities for the jupyter notebook in rpy2. For plotting there is a context manager (see https://bitbucket.org/rpy2/rpy2/issues/330/ipython-plotting-wrapper - I don't remember if there is more documentation), but the most advanced utilities are tailored for `ggplot2`. Check for example this slides and the following ones:
https://lgautier.github.io/odsc-ppda-slides/#/5/13

The full notebook is here:

https://github.com/lgautier/odsc-ppda-slides/blob/master/notebooks/slides.ipynb

There is a docker container shipping with everything needed to run the notebook:

https://github.com/lgautier/pragmatic-polyglot-data-analysis

Comment: Thanks for your answer @lgautier. Indeed, I am using jupyter. I was hoping to avoid `%%R`, since I'm still learning how to input/output data into/from it. If you know of a way to do it using robjects, I would appreciate if you could add it to your answer (but please do not remove the `%%R` part)

Comment: I added a bit about plotting in the notebook without `%%R`.